# What defines a trap-beat?

Tags: terminology, trap

I'm actually more the boom bap Hip-Hop, 90's style beat guy. But I find myself enjoying trap music more and more, since it's getting more and more popular and also because my friend is making more trap music than *normal* Hip-Hop (I can add a link if someone is interested in Swiss trap).

Now, I know trap-beats originated from Hip-Hop, but where do you draw the line? Of course there are the famous, fast hi-hats in trap music but when making a beat, when will it turn from a Hip-Hop beat to a trap-beat? Or are those two totally different?

Answer (score 6):

Typically, a trap beat is defined as having a BPM of >= 140, with hi-hats at triple-time or faster. Past that it's fairly subjective.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_music

Answer (score -1):

Go to YouTube and search either "future type beat," "migos type beat", "21 savage type beat," and that will show you the "typical" trap beat