# Is there a genre name for these new hip hop like songs with clicking drum machine?

Tags: identify-this-genre, hip-hop

Lately (especially after the release of the Black Panther movie and soundtrack) I hear on the radio and at the street a style of music that uses a specific type of a clicking (alternating between fourths and triplets) drum machine. They seem to belong to the hip-hop genre but I was wondering if there is a more specific term or genre to call them.

Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YP6G0IzrP1w

Comment: Linked with [What defines a trap beat?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/10/what-defines-a-trap-beat).

Comment: Hint: Hideri Kanzaki

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What defines a trap beat?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/10/what-defines-a-trap-beat)

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya That would be a duplicate if I knew what trap-beat is. This is actually the reverse question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to [**Trap Music**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_music) genre.

It is, like you said:

> typified by double or triple-time sub-divided hi-hats